# Evaluation issue with NDepend in CruiseControl.NET

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ndepend

I am trying to integrate NDepend with CruiseControl.NET. However, I get the following build error when I try to build any project: "ERROR:   Evaluation issue: Your evaluation period hasn't been activated yet. Please run Visual NDepend to start evaluation". I have already evaluated my NDepend trial version and I have set up the NDepend task in the ccnet config file. Please suggest what I can do!

Answer (score 1):

The evaluation mode is likely triggered for each user on the system.  Invoke NDepend manually on your build server with the user identity you use to run your CruiseControl.NET instance, dismiss the evaluation dialog, and then try your build again.